# My error is string was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, webforms

I'm having this error if i leave the date blank when I click save button.

Front Code

Date

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" CssClass="text_300" MaxLength="200"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"></asp:CalendarExtender>
<asp:MaskedEditExtender TargetControlID="txtDateFrom" Mask="99/99/9999"
    MessageValidatorTip="true" OnFocusCssClass="MaskEditFocus" OnInvalidCssClass="MaskEditError"
    MaskType="Date"
    ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" runat="server" ID="mskD" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtDate" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Back Code

```
string result = _bllstaff.addInfo(Convert.ToDateTime(this.txtDateFrom.Text == "" 
    ? 0.ToString() : this.txtDateFrom.Text), _pUser.IDUSER, 
    DateTime.Now, dtCurrentTable);
```

This error occurs if I leave it blank after click save button. Maybe you guys have idea or suggestion for me. Thank you.

Comment: Your formal parameter is defined as DateTime, not DateTime? and a DateTime cannot be null. You would be best to require this value upfront or have something to default it to if the user does not have to enter anything. I don't know what you are doing with your 0.ToString() code but "0" is not a valid DateTime value either.

Comment: Also, what is your server (and client part) Default Culture?

Comment: @lrb , silly me. i thought if i put 0 there it might put 00/00/0000 because i leave it blank.actually it can run very well, it only have problem if my date empty after i save it. =)

Comment: @agat i dont have default culture

Comment: Ok. Currently here is nothing with Culture. But you should keep in mind that the date parsing processes according to the Culture which is defined for your current Thread.

Comment: @agat do you have any example for me? or you could give me link about this for me to understand. btw, thank you. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to understand exactly what issue you are having. Maybe revising your question, posting more code, and using a code block will help. EDIT: (I see the question has been updated)

I'll attempt a suggestion however; My advice would be to use the [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, or even better [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and make the code easier to follow:

```
//...
DateTime date = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime.TryParse(this.txtDateFrom.Text, out date);
string result = _bllstaff.addInfo(date, _pUser.IDUSER, DateTime.Now, dtCurrentTable);
//...
```

Comment: This code is valid but what if DateTime.TryParse fails. Perhaps wrapping the parse function in a conditional block would add a little more stability.

Comment: +1. putting the TryParse in an `if` block would have been better

Comment: I chose not to put the TryParse in an `if` statement as the initial assignment to DateTime.MinValue has the desired effect of the original code `DateTime.Convert(0.ToString())`. I do agree though, taking it one step further and actually handling the exceptional case, and displaying an error would be the best approach.